# Junit test cases not running using maven

Tags: java, maven, junit4, powermockito

I am trying to run a maven test for the following pom. But no tests re getting picked up. Though in the maven tests its showing that the test is being compiled. I am using JUnit 4.12. I tried several things and found out that the parent pom is causing the issues. If I remove the parent pom and give its own group id and artifact Id it's working.

Can some please explain to me why it's not working with the parent pom and provide a solution for it.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-parent</artifactId>
    <version>20.6.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>ai_one_click</artifactId>
<name>one_click</name>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test</groupId>
        <artifactId>data_model</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
        <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.22.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes> <include>**/Test1.java</include> </includes>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

```
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.1.0:clean (default-clean) @ ai_one_click ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-cli) @ ai_one_click ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to one_click\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-cli) @ ai_one_click ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

I tried with various maven commands

1. clean surefire:test
2. clean test
3. clean -D maven.test.failure.ignore=true compiler:testCompile surefire:test
4. test -Dtest=Test1

Comment: Change `<groupId>com.test/groupId>` to `<groupId>com.test</groupId>` inside your dependencies configuration section of your pom.xml file.

Comment: Thanks actually it's a typo...while copying to StackOverflow, I made the mistake... actual issues is that no test cases are being picked while running maven test.

Comment: Hello @TauseefRahaman , Could you please post a screenshot image of your console to show what is actual error.

Comment: hi @amit, i had updated in the question with the console and test commands i am using.

Comment: Then we need your testing configuration and your test classes (or any MRE : minimal reproducible example). Seems your test is ignored. Have you got JUnit dependencies loaded by Maven as transitive dependencies for Mockito ? Use the POM view to get that information in Eclipse or SpringSource STS we got that view since 10 years at least.